# ADF/Web activity - Variable output issue

Tags: azure, output, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to send the output of a variable with a Web activity, but I keep getting an error message saying, "After parsing a value, an unexpected character was encountered."
I have two lookup activities to which "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table" queries are added. Additionally, there are two Set Variable activities that capture the outputs of the lookup activities, representing the number of rows returned by the queries. Finally, I have an If condition with a Web activity in the TRUE branch and another Web activity in the FALSE branch. My intention is to send a message when the number of rows between the two tables is equal or different, including the outputs of the variables to display the respective counts.

Example:

[image: Here's how I'm trying to get the output from a variable but it gives me the following error: 'After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered:]

The variable is underlined as an error because it's just an example of the syntax I'm using. The actual variable I'm using is different.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your flow of the pipeline, I tried in my environment and able to achieve your requirement.

This is the flow that I have used.

[image]

Inside the True activities of if, I have given the web activity body like below.

```
{
"Result": "True",
"message": @{variables('var1')}
}
```

[image]

**Web activity inside False activities:**

```
{
"Result": "False",
"message": "@{concat(variables('var1'),' not equals ',variables('var2'))}"
}
```

[image]

Here for web activity, I have given a sample POST URL.

**This is my pipeline JSON:**

```
{
    "name": "pipeline4",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Lookup1",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "AzureSqlSource",
                        "sqlReaderQuery": "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM sample1;",
                        "queryTimeout": "02:00:00",
                        "partitionOption": "None"
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "firstRowOnly": false
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Lookup1_copy1",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "AzureSqlSource",
                        "sqlReaderQuery": "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM sample1;",
                        "queryTimeout": "02:00:00",
                        "partitionOption": "None"
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "firstRowOnly": false
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set variable1",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Lookup1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "var1",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@string(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].count)",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set variable2",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Lookup1_copy1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "var2",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@string(activity('Lookup1_copy1').output.value[0].count)",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "If Condition1",
                "type": "IfCondition",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Set variable1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "activity": "Set variable2",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "expression": {
                        "value": "@equals(variables('var1'), variables('var2'))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "ifFalseActivities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Web1_copy1",
                            "type": "WebActivity",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "url": "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2",
                                "method": "POST",
                                "headers": {
                                    "Content-type": "application/json"
                                },
                                "body": {
                                    "value": "{\n\"Result\": \"False\",\n\"message\": \"@{concat(variables('var1'),' not equals ',variables('var2'))}\"\n}",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "ifTrueActivities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Web1",
                            "type": "WebActivity",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "url": "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2",
                                "method": "POST",
                                "headers": {
                                    "Content-type": "application/json"
                                },
                                "body": {
                                    "value": "{\n\"Result\": \"True\",\n\"message\": @{variables('var1')}\n}",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "var1": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "var2": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and I apologize for the delayed response. Here's what I used and I'm currently getting the expected result : @{replace(string(variables('Var1')),'"','''')}, @{replace(string(variables('Var2')),'"','''')}"